# Can I install elementary os on a atom x5Z8350 and will it run well?

Tags: system-installation

I have 4 gigs of ddr3 and have a 60 gig ssd. I am looking to replace windows

Answer (score 0):

Here are the specs you need:

- Recent Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor
- 4 GB of system memory (RAM)
- Solid state drive (SSD) with 15 GB of free space
- 1024×768 display

https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation

Your RAM and Hard Drive meet the requirements. Looks like your processor is a Quad-core 64-bit.  I'd say elementary OS will run on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely yes. I'm running eOS on a machine with Intel Core M3-7Y30 which is dual core and runs up to 2,6 GHz with turbo boost, otherwise it's 1 GHz max, 4 gb ram and 128 ssd and it runs nice and smoothly

Answer (score 0):

I would say to increase RAM to 8GB - better performance with double of what you have now. Unless your